Подключение VPCS к более, чем одному VLAN'у
Всем салют, нужна помощь в GNS3 по VLAN'ам. Моя задача создать три VLAN'a:

VLAN20 для PC1 и PC3
VLAN30 для PC2 и PC4
VLAN40 для PC1 и PC2

Основу я подготовил:

Настроил trunk соединения и dot1q на соответствующих интерфейсах коммутаторов SW3(f1/2, f1/0, f1/1), SW2(f1/0), SW1(f1/0)

Создал vtp домен, где SW3 сервер, SW2 и SW1  - клиенты

Создал 3 VLAN на SW3: VLAN20, VLAN30, VLAN40


Насколько я знаю, за раз я могу настроить только одно access соединение для VLAN, например, на SW1 для f1/1 switchport access vlan 20. Если я для этого же интерфейса введу access соединение для другого VLAN, то прошлое затрется новым значением.
Значит, первый вопрос: как мне сделать access для нескольких VLAN(знаю, что для trunk соединения можно настроить видимость для нескольких VLAN, но мне нужно ведь access здесь, если не так, то поправьте)
Второй вопрос - как тогда работать с субинтерфейсами роутера? Я знаю, что для конкретного VLAN можно легко прописать encapsulation dot1Q (номер VLAN) и ip-адрес(который будет default gateway для хоста), но что делать в случае, когда у меня два PC должны быть в двух VLAN одновременно и какой тогда задавать gateway.
P.S. метки задал как cisco packet tracer, так как не нашел с gns3.



access для нескольких VLAN

никак. Если к порту подключена PC у которой на сетевом интерфейсе сконфигурированы саб.интерфейсы (eth0.1, eth0.2 ...), то и порт SW 1/1 будет работать в режиме trunk с соответствующим набором разрешенных vlan.

Второй вопрос - как тогда работать с субинтерфейсами роутера

ответ выше.
PC
├── eth0.1 IP 10.0.0.2/24 -> vlan2 -> 1/1(trunk)SW1(trunk)1/0 -> IP 10.0.0.1/24 1/0 (sub.iface) R1
└── eth0.2 IP 10.0.1.2/24 -> vlan3 -> 1/1(trunk)SW1(trunk)1/0 -> IP 10.0.0.2/24 1/0 (sub.iface) R1

Спасибо за ответ, но я мало что понял. Можно сказать по конкретней для каких коммутаторов и для каких интерфейсов что я должен прописывать?

Router:
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no shutdown

interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/0.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0

SW3:
vlan 20
vlan 30
vlan 40
interface range fastethernet 1/0 - 2
   switchport mode trunk
   switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

SW1:
vlan 20
vlan 30
vlan 40
interface range fastethernet 1/0 - 2
   switchport mode trunk
   switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

SW2:
vlan 20
vlan 30
vlan 40
interface fastethernet 1/0
   switchport mode trunk
   switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
interface fastethernet 1/1
   switchport mode access
   switchport access vlan 20
interface fastethernet 1/2
   switchport mode access
   switchport access vlan 30

и конфиг сетевого интерфейса PC1, который должен иметь сетевое взаимодействие с вланами 20,40
# Основной интерфейс без IP-адреса
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

# Подинтерфейс для VLAN 20
auto eth0.20
iface eth0.20 inet static
    address 192.168.20.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vlan-raw-device eth0

# Подинтерфейс для VLAN 40
auto eth0.40
iface eth0.40 inet static
    address 192.168.40.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vlan-raw-device eth0

и конфиг сетевого интерфейса PC3, который должен иметь сетевое взаимодействие только с вланом 20 (судя по вашей топологии и требованиям)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.20.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0

конфиги PC2 и PC4 похожи на PC1 и PC3 соответственно. Меняются только номера виланов и IP адреса.

VLAN это всего лишь broadcast домен. Просто держите это в голове.
